# How to merge the value of input boxes Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 input box, and each input box Have a different value .. how i can merge the value of the input boxes and compare it, then alert or do something ..

Example:

```
<form>
            <input id="input1" type="text">
            <input id ="input2" type = "text"/>
            <input id ="input3" type = "text"/>
            <input id = "input4" type = "text"/>
            <input id = "input5" type = "text"/>
</form>

    var input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    var input3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
    var input4 = document.getElementById('input4').value;
    var input5 = document.getElementById('input5').value;
    var wordsConcat = input1.concat(input2,input3,input4,input5);
```

//after merging Compare the words to SAMPLE;

Comment: loop them and read the values...What have you tried. What do you mean by merge?

Comment: compare in the sense if present in wordsconcat or the entire concatinated word is sample???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** method in jQuery

```
var a='';
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
   a+=this.value;
});
if (a === "SAMPLE") {
     //do something
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/cnxF6/4/)

Answer (score 9):

You've tagged jQuery so I'm assuming it's available to you.

You can map each input to a value, and then `join()` them together using an empty string:

```
var vals = $('input').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get().join('');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NUH4w/4/)

**ES6:**

```
const vals = $('input').map((_, elem) => elem.value).get().join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sample = 'your word';
if(wordsConcat === sample){
   alert('a');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    inputValue = "";
    for (var index=0; index < inputs.length; index ++ ) {
        inputValue += inputs[index].value;
    }
    if (inputValue === "SAMPLE") {
         //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = $('input[type="text"]').map(function(i, e){
    return e.value;
}).get();

//do compare stuff on result
```